# Python not finding pip modules MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have installed some modules using pip and whenever I try to import them in Python I am told that no module exists. I think there is something wrong with my paths. This is some terminal output, does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:~ nickporter$ which python
/usr/bin/python
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:~ nickporter$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:~ nickporter$
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `python --version` and `pip --version`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip freeze` to find the packages installed.
I do not know whether you use a virtualenv. If you use it, you have to source it, to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably have multiple installations of Python or pip (or both).  First, determine if you have multiple Python binaries installed and decide on the one you want to use by default.

You clearly have `/usr/bin/python`...check if there is another one in `/usr/local/bin/python`.  If you *do* have one in `/usr/local/bin`, I'm guessing you installed it with Homebrew.  Pick the Python you want to use (if there are multiple) by playing with your `PATH`.  If you want to use `/usr/local/bin/python` (assuming it exists) ensure `/usr/local/bin` comes *before* `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`.

Once you do that, I would *remove* your current `pip`.  After you remove it, look for it again with `which pip`, just to make sure you don't have any old one laying around.  Once you've totally removed it, reinstall.

If you're installing with Homebrew, I'd stick to using the Homebrew python and `pip`.  If you're *not* using Homebrew I'd install pip using: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

`curl -q https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

Answer (score 0):

You have homebrew version of python shadowed by the system python, but because system python doesn't have pip, a pip you see is actually a brew one.

I found, that the reason for this is that brew by default names python2.7 as python2 in */usr/local/bin* (probably for preventing possible compatibility issues with some system services (?)) , i.e. you may try to run *python2* or try to *ln /usr/local/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python* and restart the term session.

Make sure that /usr/local/bin goes before /usr/bin and /bin in your $PATH.

BTW. *brew info {package}* often contains recommendations for proper configuration of packages.